# Bootstrap Carousel has delayed/jumpy transition

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap carousel in a react project and the carousel keeps jumping between images. I believe the reason for this is because the images are big, and I am just resizing them to have them fit nicely in the carousel. It only happens once which is I believe it is due to the resizing since they would have been resized once it loads the first time. I have also tried commenting out the resizing and see how the images load and while they are giant, they do smoothly transition between each other.

I have tried using the bootstrap class "img-fluid". And have also tried writing my own CSS to resize it how I want. Neither have worked for me though.

React code:

```
<Carousel className={classes.carousel}>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      src={image1}
      alt="image1"
      className="img-fluid"
    />
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      src={image2}
      alt="image2"
      className="img-fluid"
    />
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img
      src={iamge3}
      alt="image3"
      className="img-fluid"
    />
  </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

CSS code:

```
.carousel {
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 6%;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas for a workaround this or if this is not actually what's happening I would appreciate that.

Comment: I'm wondering how we should debug this without your images. Have you tried taking another random images?

Comment: @IgorGonak It shouldn't really matter what images you use as long as they are bigger than the carousel. The image sizes I'm using personally are 5333x3548, 6048x4024, and 3452x5188.

Comment: When I copy/paste your code and take a fake 5333x3548 image, the images are stretched awkwardly: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-bhabha-oey563 What is exactly you are trying to acheive? how should it look like? Are you using images with different aspect ratios? What do you mean by jumpy transition?

Comment: @IgorGonak That's odd. I tried using the holder.js as well in my actual project to test it out and I get the same effect. You can take a better look [here](http://carousel.parkermossel.com/) after doing this though I'm not sure if it's as much the size as just the images loading slowly. If that's the case, I could try to implement some lazy loading which I have already tried but it failed since I don't know the best way to do that with react.

Comment: I guess it's just the huge image size. Do you really need such a high resolution? Maybe try to use thumbnail images. Btw, did you try the Image component of react-bootstrap library? Same result?

Comment: @IgorGonak I just tried the Image component to the same result. They don't need to be such a high resolution. I have some compressed versions of them, and while it is better it still produces the same result. If there is a way to compress them more then I'll gladly do it but in the past compressing images when I have tried to compress it more than once I usually get some message saying "image can't be compressed any further" or something like that. I looked at thumbnail images and aside from giving me a white border which I don't want the rest of the CSS on it is the same as I already have.